# Unable to render Component dynamically through Object.entries

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to reduce my code and render a series of MUI rows through a loop and `Object.entries`. Though each time that I try to extract the value of a sperate Object, I get this

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Chalk'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Chalk'.
> rowLabels and chalk keys match.

```
const ConfigureRowValue = () => {
  const rowLabels = {
    sling: "Load",
    bump: "Bump Priority",
    equipment: "Key Equipment",
    w: "Key W",
    notes: "Notes",
  };
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(rowLabels)) {
    return (
      <>
        <ChalkCardDataRow label={`${value}`} value={`${chalk[key]}`} />
      </>
    );
  }
};

//...

type ChalkCardDataRowProps = {
  label: string,
  value: string | null,
};

export const ChalkCardDataRow = ({ label, value }: ChalkCardDataRowProps) => {
  return (
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell style={{ borderBottom: "none" }}>{label}:</TableCell>
      <TableCell align={"right"} style={{ borderBottom: "none" }}>
        <Typography color="grey">{value ?? "-"}</Typography>
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
};
```

If I explicitly insert the component multiple times it works but causes too much code duplication. i.e:

```
<ChalkCardDataRow label={"Sling Load"} value={chalk.sling} />
<ChalkCardDataRow label={"Bump Priority"} value={chalk.bump} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `Object.entries` return type gives the keys as `string`, instead of `keyof object`. See [ms/TS#12253](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) for explanations on this design choice.

The usual workaround is to use a type assertion in this case, since you are sure that both objects have the same keys: `chalk[key as keyof typeof rowLabels]`

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=37&pln=26&pc=67#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4cB3AGRQCMkAbOuAXjgBvcnFFw6XYDQDmALgIsIKACb4ANCLHsAruHn4AQrrBwAClGDRgMAJ7rNopAEdtwMCCQ0Y+gNJIbcACiLm4eXvZicEy+-nAA6hFiNBAwSHT6AHIpafYAvhRUtAxwaAAWKFwA1vxCDuKSMvplFZWJojp6BM1VbXDOru6e3l3lPRqR0SMtvcmp6VNj5PmUABQAlPwAfLWR1PSMadpc8AIA2gC6dZjQcCt7xaeV-mpwAG4V2kjncBCYcADy7AAVkgMAA6IYWNIrZhsTg8NYbYSRSJEOhHGBgsDaOilFZ1FFiAA8mwJhJRRIAwqNKpSUFBlAARFAwFAICBMMnk8lcDjcPiCAAGABJBO8uJ9coLclzuSjxZ8BSLBN1Ko9YiheE8bL84LYwEhdbC+TxzlKZXLyQB6UmW0REm2ytYUSIymXkfVIODUlp0hnM1nspjmCBgXgCZFiXnw+QMCwyF1iBVIWMwePSOAAHzgNCOXAoy3u8B9VT9TJZbI5NRWgjg0e4L2TcFy8hLtPp5cDHJDYY2fG2taIMG0UBoObzzaAA)

---

Another solution would be to use [`ts-extras/objectEntries`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ts-extras/blob/main/source/object-entries.ts):

> A strongly-typed version of `Object.entries()`.

```
import {objectEntries} from 'ts-extras';

for (const [key, value] of objectEntries(rowLabels)) {
  result.push(
    <>
      <ChalkCardDataRow
        label={`${value}`}
        value={`${chalk[key]}`} // Okay
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=44&pln=27&pc=52#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzggCMArJDAUQDsYpgkBnOAF842XARj8AtEgAePFPzLlyaCJ37wcAdwAyKRkgA2ggLx1ycK3H5HgnAOYAuArogoAJvgA0l64wBXcBd8ACEgsDgABV5oYBgATx8-KyQARwDgMBAkbhCAaSQEuHYMrJzuZOs4bQKiuAB1KutOCBgBEIA5NoFkoQpVdU04NAALFCMAazhzWhSbO0cQsYnJ5qtA4IIVqfW4dMzs3Jhl8d3fatrts7WLlp7+U9W+gYAKAEoZgD4LarUNLQCAJGeDmADaAF15phoHBXv9hmDJkVvHAAG4TAJICEMTAMFhsGBcHh8fivHT6Qwmd6fObVapEfjAmAAOjAAX4o1e83p1gAPF8ebz6XyAMI3UUoKAeAAiKBgKAQEG0QuFwqMBmMploAAMACS0DFGLFCHVCVVq+lGrHa-W0HaTJFFCGmkQAejdcAA8pMUAkLWq3YLLfygxb3hRqubzeREmAkHBxatJdK5QqldoYhAwGZftYNVSXJpeI5I9ZrUgiyTHHAAD5wTjAowUfqDAGJiVS2XyxXKmZw+gF4yoivCFxJqYp7vp5VZnOfUw-ehEGABKCcBtN4RAA)

Comment: Darn, just tried the `${chalk[key]}`, and still gave me the same error. Thank you for the suggestion. Going to try the ts-extra/ObjectEntriesc