# React TS change Object Value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a useState object of:

```
const [filterState,setFilterState] = useState({
        Brands:{
            NewBalance: false,
            Nike: false,
            Addiddas: false,
            Converse:false,
            UnderArmour:false,
        },
        Gender:{
            Male: false,
            Female: false,
            Kids:false,
        }
    });
```

and i am rendering each brand as a checkbox like this:

```
{
  Object.entries(filterState.Brands).map(([brand, checked])=>
     <div className="" key={brand} >
         <label htmlFor={brand} className="mr-[10px]">{brand}: </label>
         <input type="checkbox" name={brand} className="cursor-pointer" checked={checked} 
         onChange={()=>setFilterState({Brands:{...filterState.Brands,Nike:!checked},Gender: 
         {...filterState.Gender}})}/>
         </div>
)}
```

If you look at the onChange that's where I have the problem:

```
onChange={()=>setFilterState({Brands{...filterState.Brands,Nike:!checked},Gender{...filterState.Gender}})}/>
```

, if I give it an exact key like `Nike` then I have no issue but that only changes one checkbox. If I change the `Nike` to `brand` then I get an error of: `'brand' does not exist in type ...`  How do I make this work as brand is technically a string so it doesn't work, how do I make it check/uncheck the correct boxes, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to render Component dynamically through Object.entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331168/unable-to-render-component-dynamically-through-object-entries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is not really TS friendly, try changing to the following object style.

```
  const [filterState,setFilterState] = useState<Shoes>({
    brand:[{
        brand: "NewBalance",
        checked: false,
    },
    {
        brand: "Nike",
        checked: false,
    },
    ......
   ],
   gender: [{

   }]
})
```

Then you can declare your type as something like

```
type Brand = {
  brand: string;
  checked: boolean;
}

type Gender = {
  gender: "Male" | "Female" | "Kid";
  checked: boolean;
}

type Shoes = {
  gender: Array<Gender>; 
  brand: Array<Brand>;
}
```

Then you no longer need to use `Object.entries`, you can use basic maps and filter

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-grass-qi557m?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: hi, im starting to implement it this way, thanks but when making it im getting an error of: Type '{ brand: string; checked: false; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Brand': brand, checked . What am i doing wrong?  thanks

Comment: ahh u need to change type Shoes, brand: Brand to brand: Array<Brand> , please see a simplified version of the implementation https://codesandbox.io/s/black-grass-qi557m?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your onChange. Should be:

```
onChange={()=>setFilterState({Brands:{...filterState.Brands,Nike:!checked},Gender:{...filterState.Gender}})}/>
```

A bit more legibly, that's:

```
onChange={() => setFilterState({ 
  Brands: { ...filterState.Brands, Nike: !checked },
  Gender: {...filterState.Gender }
})}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The typing of `Object.entries` can be improved.

```
// an alias that has a better typing than the original.
const entries: <T extends object>(o: T) => ({ [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T])[] = Object.entries;

const [filterState, setFilterState] = useState({
    Brands: {
        NewBalance: false,
        Nike: false,
        Addiddas: false,
        Converse: false,
        UnderArmour: false,
    },
    Gender: {
        Male: false,
        Female: false,
        Kids: false,
    }
});

entries(filterState.Brands).map(([brand, checked]) =>
    <div className="" key={brand} >
        <label htmlFor={brand} className="mr-[10px]">{brand}: </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name={brand} className="cursor-pointer" checked={checked}
            onChange={() => setFilterState(prev => ({ ...prev, Brands: { ...prev.Brands, [brand]: !checked } }))} />
    </div>
)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#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-atHAACEj5INENA0Nk2S0PwE4PMOoZZtkQA)